# Subtle gray outline appearing around select images

Tags: html, css

For some reason there is a slight gray outline visible around a few of my product images. The actual images themselves do not contain this and I've also tried applying the following CSS with no success:

```
img {
border: 0px !important;
outline: 0 !important;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the gray outline: (very subtle, but should not be there)

[image]

On some monitors the gray outline is visible without zooming in and on other monitors it's only visible when zooming in... Visible in all browsers.

Does anyone know why this may be happening? site: missingnewyork.com/collage-playing-cards-by-missing

Comment: first of all provided image dosen't display any gray outline. secondly you should check image in browser and mention the browser don't check in more computers,.. and provide some more detials.

Comment: The gray line is visible in the provided image. If it’s not visible for you, perhaps try opening the image full screen and then zooming in. I’ve also updated the description with more details. Thank you!

Comment: The last pixel column is not black. In fact its somewhere around `rgba(10, 10, 10, 1)` meaning a dark gray, but definitely noticeable. This is pure speculation but the column `rgba` values seem to move around a bit which makes me suspect that this image was part of a larger atlas and you are dealing with block boundary artifacts. But either way, the line is visible because there is a line in the image. The reason you see this at certain zoom levels and different browsers is because the image is being down scaled and those minute details are typically filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

You're right its very hard to see but it is slightly visible, but without seeing the rest of your code (html) I would guess there are two divs beside each other with slightly different black colors? My suggestion would be to check that both colours are exactly the same and then if the problem persists edit your comment to add all of your code... html and the rest of your css